# What combination of boost tools allows to use abstract factory design pattern?

Tags: boost, abstract-factory, static-polymorphism, boost-functional

From what I understand, a combination of boost::function, boost::factory and std::map allows for a creation of object factory. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html
Loki has abstract factory but for some reason boost doesn't have it.
What would be the boost way to use abstract factory pattern?

One way I can think of is by abstracting an interface for creating the products manually -- by creating products with the same creation policy.

I'd be more happy if your answer uses static polymorphism.